Motorizing a tv mount
Let me preface my question by a disclaimer: I don't know for sure if the format of this question fits this forum, I hope it does. Here it goes:
I recently bought a tv mount from Amazon, which is basically a swivel arm with a joint in the middle. Pictures to illustrate (red are joints):


What I would like to do is motorize the whole thing (every joint). There are some challenges along the way I haven't been able to solve though, mainly because of the high joint stiffness (I haven't measured, but per my estimation I need some 3-4 kg of force, sorry, 30-40 Newtons pulling on the tv mount platform to extend the arm). Let me present some of the ideas I went through:

Somehow actually put a motor on each joint. Issues: High joint stiffness and small leverage at the joints means high required torque, means big and heavy motors, not good. Also, attaching them would be pretty annoying, especially at the middle joint, as you can see, transfer of torque to the second segment sandwiched in the middle would not be fun.

Some form of linear motor / pneumatic cylinder / between the arm segments and the wall and tv mount, like an excavator. Issues: High joint stiffness and small leverage again means high required force. Not only that, but at angles around 0 and 180 degress, the force applied by those actuators would be multiplied by nearly 0, as most of the force would not produce torque. Also: Those actuators can't contract to length 0 and they take up space, meaning that generally, the arm propably would not be able to contract all the way.

Some form of rope-pulley system. Different sub ideas:
--3.1 Have all of the pulleys either at the wall mount or the tv mount, all attaching to different points on the other side. With 3 pulleys, I should be able to constrain the whole system. Issue: Since the pulleys can only pull, not push, I would need to have, for example, springs between the arm segements pushing them apart, so that the pulleys can pull against that force and fix the system in place (otherwise, the arm could only close, not open). Springs would have the same torque issue explained beforce, and they would also produce a non constant force depending on the arm segments angle.
--3.2 Have all pulleys at the wall mount and let ropes go along the arm, attaching at either side of each joint and turning them that way. Propably best solution, but again, the issue of needing very high pulling force while needing at least a decent leverage everywhere (meaning a large pulley on each joint? ugly) remains.


I'm kind of out of ideas at this point, do you guys have further ideas / suggestions, or remarks on my ideas so far? I would be very grateful for answers.

examine how your own arm moves

@jsotola no offense, but what exactly is that supposed to do for me? I am aware of the biomechanics of arms, and if you read point 3.2 of my rather lengthy description of my ideas so far, you see something pretty similar to a muscle-tendon system. Also, muscles aren't that easy to replicate as linear actuators.

my comment is in response to Since the pulleys can only pull, not push, I would need to have, for example, springs between the arm segements pushing them apart ... you don't have to use linear actuators ... a cable and pulley system would work exactly the same way

@jsotola yeah, that's what I meant with "attaching at either side of each joint" in 3.2. I see the misunderstanding now tho, I haven't explained that clearly enough...with the original pulley system, I meant pulleys that go from the tv mount platform directly to the wall mount, basically skipping all the joints

Do you want this system to alternate between 2 states (at the wall to fully extended) or do you need more flexibility?
